# JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE onHide event?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener

I have a `WorldEditor` JFrame that launches a `Game` JFrame. However, when the `Game` closes, I don't want it to end the entire program, so I set the default close operation to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`. But, to save resources, I pause the `WorldEditor` while the `Game` is running.

How can I detect when the `Game` window is hidden so I can resume `WorldEditor`?

Comment: [How to write window listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html)

Comment: I came across that, but `windowClosed` doesn't trigger..

Comment: Well it's not being closed, now is it?

Comment: How about windowDeactivated?

Comment: @camickr According to the docs that's triggered when the window loses focus

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins. correct. When you hide a window the focus has to go somewhere, usually to the last window that had focus. By the way after rereading your question you don't need to do anything special. Just use DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE. The Game frame will close, but your WorldEditor frame will still be open.

Comment: as @camickr said, after a frame is disposed the `windowClosed()` event should be triggered. Note that when hitting the close-button-decorator will trigger `windowClosing()` event. Whatever you approach will be, you can resume the `WorldEditor` using those events.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you hide the frame yourself instead of using a default `HIDE_ON_CLOSE`?

```
// inside WindowListener class
public windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    yourFrame.setVisible( false );
    // your code here...
}
```

Edit made: from docs:

> The default close operation is executed after any window listeners
>   handle the window-closing event. So, for example, assume that you
>   specify that the default close operation is to dispose of a frame. You
>   also implement a window listener that tests whether the frame is the
>   last one visible and, if so, saves some data and exits the
>   application. Under these conditions, when the user closes a frame, the
>   window listener will be called first. If it does not exit the
>   application, then the default close operation — disposing of the frame
>   — will then be performed.

New edit with a working example:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ListenerTest extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListenerTest frame = new ListenerTest();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible( true );
}

public ListenerTest() {
    this.addWindowListener( this );
}

public void windowActivated(WindowEvent e) {
    System.out.println(" activated ");
}
public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(" closed ");
}
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(" closing ");
}
public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(" deactivated ");
}
public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(" deiconified ");
}
public void windowIconified(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(" iconified ");
}
public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e){
    System.out.println(" opened ");
}
}
```

Test this out in order to catch <del>what</del> which events are firing.

Comment: As stated in this answer, the `windowClosing` event will fire when using `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` as the default close operation. I've tested this in my own application and it works.